# R reticulate specifying python executable to use

Tags: python, r, rstudio, arcgis, reticulate

First, I'm working on a Windows machine. I would like to specify a specific version of python to use in RStudio. I would like RStudio to use python 3 in the ArcGIS Pro folder in order to have `arcpy` available, along with the licensed extensions. I have `reticulate` installed and have tried the following methods to force RStudio to use the ArcGIS Pro version of python.

First I tried this:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe", required = TRUE)
```

The resulting error:

```
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Following some other tips, I tried setting the environment before loading the reticulate library.

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "c:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe")
library(reticulate)
```

Then I retrieve information about the the version of Python currently being used by reticulate.

```
py_config
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

I also tried creating and editing the `.Renviron` by using the `usethis` package

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

Then entering the following

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe"
```

And saving it, restarting R..

```
library (reticulate)
py_config()
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

And, to confirm, here is the location...
[image]

Any ideas on why I continue to receive `invalid 'path' argument`

UPDATE (1/11/24): This doesn't seem to be an issue with the `reticulate` package anymore. My current configuration is R version: 4.3.2, reticulate version: 1.34.0, RStudio version: 2023.12.0, ArcGIS Pro version: 3.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue. After trying a whole assortment of things, I finally installed an archived version of reticulate (reticulate_1.22) instead of using the most up-to-date version (reticulate_1.23) and now the issue is gone. It appears that this bug has been brought to the developers' attention (https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1189).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing `Program Files` with `PROGRA~1` and have you maybe also checked for example a command like `dir("path/to/your/env")` although tbh your screenshot looks ok;

btw just in case - after editing your .Renviron file you need to restart your RStudio/R session for changes to take effect;
RStudio version 2022.02 has `Python interpreter` selection now available in `Global Options`
[image]

Comment: I just tried your suggestions, still the same error. My thought is that maybe something in my computer's system variables is creating this error. Unfortunately I don't have admin rights on this machine but will investigate my system variables and possibly delete path variable.

Comment: this could be the case if you installed some Python or Anaconda version that modifies your path? But you should be able to easily check that with `Sys.getenv()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
use_python("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3")
```

Comment: Different error when using your suggestion. Error in system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  : 
  '"C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3"' not found

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error with R version R-4.1.1, but when I switched back to the previous version R-4.0.5 everything worked as expected. It's a quick workaround but doesn't solve the underlying issue in the current version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).